# How to avoid easyhook injecting dll multiple times?

Tags: hook, easyhook

The target app could be injected multiple times with same dll.

This will lead the same function be hooked multiple times.

Do you know if there is a way to detect if the target app is already injected? or is there a way to avoid multiple injection?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the DLL is already loaded in the target application before proceeding with the injection:

- In .NET you can use the [Process.Modules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.modules(v=vs.110).aspx) property to iterate over the loaded DLLs in a process.
- For native C/C++ you can use the Windows Process Status API method [EnumProcessModules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631(v=vs.85).aspx) to achieve the same result. An example of iterating the modules for processes can be [found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682621(v=vs.85).aspx).

Alternatively you could use a named system mutex within your DLL that is being injected to ensure that your hook creation logic is not applied multiple times. See the [Mutex class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx) for .NET, or [CreateMutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx) for native. This would be more complicated approach, and require you to cleanup the mutex when the hooks are removed.